# Bash - meaning of the semicolon after the command

Tags: bash

> A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the
>   operators ‘;’, ‘&’, ‘&&’, or ‘||’, and optionally terminated by one of
>   ‘;’, ‘&’, or a newline.

I can't find an explanation, what does semicolon (;) do after the last command. For instance, what's the difference between the following two commands:

`a;b;c`

`a;b;c;`

?

Comment: A `;` at the end of a command does nothing. Well, it acts as a command terminator, just like newline does. There is no difference between the two lists of commands that you show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *final* semicolon is entirely optional. If it is there it does nothing differently than if it is not.